# How to clear cin input buffer

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    string inputName;
    int age;
    // Set exception mask for cin stream
    cin.exceptions(ios::failbit);

    cin >> inputName;
    while (inputName != "-1") {
        // FIXME: The following line will throw an ios_base::failure.
        //        Insert a try/catch statement to catch the exception.
        //        Clear cin's failbit to put cin in a useable state.

        try
        {
            cin >> age;
            cout << inputName << " " << (age + 1) << endl;
        }

        catch (ios_base::failure& excpt)
        {
            age = 0;
            cout << inputName << " " << age << endl;
            cin.clear(80, '\n');

        }

        inputName = "";

        cin >> inputName;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm unable to clear cin after catching the exception, even trying to set the variable to an empty string... my program stops at cin >> inputName; after the exception is caught but I thought cin.clear(80, '\n'); resets cin and puts it in a usable state?

Debugger is telling me that there is an unhandled exception when I try to input another string into inputName variable. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your program [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfa16fd0a9a1a75f).  [`std::cin.clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) only accepts one value: the new state to set.

Comment: Input is always text, so the issue is whether the text can be converted to an integer. And the way to do that is to check whether the conversion succeeded: `if (std::cin >> age) { /* do something with age */ } else { /* input failed; recover */ }`. That's the usual idiom, and it's much simpler than trying to deal with exceptions.

Comment: `clear` sets the stream state flags. It does not remove data. You need to `clear` the stream and then `ignore` the bad input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want to fix. In any case, I just fixed the problem with cleaning the cin.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string inputName;
    int age;
    
    // Set exception mask for cin stream
    cin.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    
    cout << "Input name: ";
    cin >> inputName;
    while (inputName != "-1") {
        // FIXME: The following line will throw an ios_base::failure.
        //        Insert a try/catch statement to catch the exception.
        //        Clear cin's failbit to put cin in a useable state.
        try {
            cout << "Age: ";
            cin >> age;
            cout << inputName << " " << (age + 1) << endl;
            break;
        }
        catch (ios_base::failure& except) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I don't pass any parameters to `cin.clear()` as this method simply `resets the state flags` inside the cin. To empty the `cin buffer` instead you have to use `cin.ignore()` passing **two parameters**, the first is the `size of the buffer`, in this case, I used **numeric_limits** to specify it, while the second parameter is to tell it what the `end character` is.

Comment: `clear` is, in my opinion, a poorly chosen name. It does more than just reset the flags. It allows you to set them. As you go looking through the deep-dark of C++ documentation, you'll find a lot of "And then calls `clear`" in places where you wouldn't think it makes sense to clear.

Comment: In older C++ Standards you'll also have to manually set `age` to 0 in the `catch` block.

Comment: I'll tell you, I don't know much about this, because it's never really helped me. But it would be quite interesting... I'm going to study this method better just for mere curiosity

Comment: I no longer take into consideration the old standard. In the sense that now when I write code I always start from the fact that it must not be under the C++17 standard

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not quite understanding how to properly clear the cin buffer but this was a simple and clean solution. I did not know that cin.ignore(); was needed along with cin.clear();

Comment: Imagine, we're here to help each other <3 @SeeLamb

Comment: @StellarClown I'd love to work in that world, but I'm often maintaining decades-old systems.

Comment: Well, of course. Everyone adapts to their own needs hahaha @user4581301

Comment: Yeah, still it's It's 2022, so the main reason I brought it up is that the asker had an `age = 0;` in about the right place for it in a pre-C++11 compiler and schools... Man, some of then use compilers so old that even I won't support them anymore.

Comment: Oh, you're right. But in this case I don't think so. From personal experience I can tell you that if it had been school code it would have called the c++ code but would still have used c libraries like stdio.h... Unfortunately in schools there is this habit of saying that c++ is explained but having the techniques of the c. I don't see what's wrong with teaching C directly and explaining how we arrived at today's technologies... Or at least, here in Italy, unfortunately, high school computer science is done by teachers who are 70 years old and have never worked with pc...

Comment: I used to get a kick out of the number of different languages I could spot the bones of in assignments. It wasn't unusual to see that the assignment had been ported from Fortran to Pascal to Modula2 to C to Java to C++. I can imagine the Go people joining in with the head-shaking in another few years

Comment: I think the main problem is also in the universities. Where to first year people, it is not explained how important a standard and official documentation is. It's not hard to find college freshmen who believe that C++11 is the latest innovation... Anyway, thanks for reminding me of this little detail. From now, each of my answers will also have a part for the moment, explaining the standard and opening more paths for newbies <3